# How to disable click on input?

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events

I am developing an app for the iPad. (It's an internal app, so it really only is for the iPad and no other device.)

On page 1 of the app I have a link to page 2. However, because I need to stay in standalone mode, I've prevented the default click behaviour on the link and instead changed the `location` object. Page 2 happens to have a text input at the exact same coordinates as the link I've just clicked. Even though I've disabled the click behavior on the link, a click event is now firing on the input which is where the link was. (This is because of the lag between the firing of `touchend` and the firing of `click`.)

I have tried both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` on clicks of the input, but the click event is still firing and opening the iPad's keyboard.

Any ideas how to stop this?  Thanks.

**Edit**: Setting the input to `readonly` or `disabled` is not an options, as the input needs to work when a user intentionally gives it focus (and I will use a `touchend` event to accomplish this).

The problem is that on the first page a user touches a link, triggering `touchend` and `click` events. The `touchend` changes `location.pathname`, and the `click` event fires after the second page has loaded. Because the second page has a text field at the same coordinates where the `click` event was triggered, `event.target` becomes the `input`, and all attempts to disable this event have failed so far.

Comment: You could set a touchend event listener inside the click listener that prevents the default and removes itself. This way only the first click would be cancelled.

Comment: Thank you -- this wasn't the solution but pointed me in the right direction. I added `event.stopPropagation` and `event.preventDefault` to the method that changes `location.pathname` on `touchend` and that prevented the click on the form from being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the input as a readonly?

Comment: I don't want it to be readonly. It's a legitimate input. I want the input to gain focus and the keyboard to display when a user actively clicks into it (and for this I will use a touch event later). However, I don't want the input to gain focus simply because the input is at the same coordinates the finger was when touching the link to change views.

Comment: @DerekHenderson move these details to the question.  It may help people better understand what your after.

Comment: Its the only input? Because if thats the case gets focus immediately and the keyboard appear. (better UX for mobile/tablets)

Comment: @JonathanMuszkat, there are 3 inputs in the form, but obviously only one of them is at the same coordinates as the previous page's anchor. I've inspected the event, and a click event on that specific input has definitly been fired.

Answer (score 0):

Overlay the window with a spinner when you are transitioning from Page 1 to Page 2. A delay of 250-300ms should be more than sufficient time for the user to get their paw off of the screen.

Comment: If I'm going to go down this option, I'd rather set the inputs to `readonly`, then set a timeout to remove the `readonly` attribute after about 200ms. However, that doesn't answer the question of how to prevent/cancel/disable the click event.